# How Array/ArrayList goes direct to the index of object? Or How ArrayList get to know that the object is stored at this place?

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, collections, random-access

in the interview room,the interviewer asked me a question that how arraylist is so fast,i said that it implements RandomAccess, but he asked how random access beneficial for searching the object in memory area?
Do you want to say that objects are stored in line in the memory and it goes to the 10th index for example

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question a little bit? The two answers in here seem to talk about different (although related) things because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is just the starting point of a chunk of memory along with a data type (int, boolean, String, etc.). The data type is used to determine how far apart the elements are spaced.

A Java `ArrayList` is similar to an array, but with additional features.

When using an array (or any array-related data structure), individual read/write operations are fast and completely unrelated to the total size of the array. If you want the one millionth array element, it's a single calculation to determine where that element is (one million * `<size of each element>`) – no scanning or searching involved.

There are lots of great resources online where you can [read more about arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure). It's worth building a solid understanding of arrays, not just for job interview purposes but also for general understanding of how computers work.

Answer (score 0):

Because ArrayList is a resizable array implementation of the List interface.
Please refer below link for understanding it well:

[ArrayList Internal Working](https://www.codenuclear.com/how-arraylist-works-internally-java/)